# NHibernate 2.1.2 - how to disable reflection optimizer

Tags: c#, nhibernate, reflection, orm

I want to disable reflection optimization (testing purposes), but i don't know where to do it. NH 2.1.2 uses hibernate-configuration in XML, and docs clearly state that this setting can not be set here. :/ I tried doing it the old App.config way with key/value pairs, no luck ...

Also, did NH 2+ version change something about reflection optimization?

Comment: It seems you can disable it by setting Environment.UseReflectionOptimizer to false, but it doesn't seem to change anything. Also, I tried directly changing this setting in properties collection of Configuration object, just before Configure() method. Same effect though ...

Comment: Btw, I was doing this to examine the effects of this setting, because of high startup cost of this optimization. I know I can serialize the config, split my mappings etc. to reduce startup time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
<add key="hibernate.use_reflection_optimizer" value="false" />
```

?

---

[**From the Hibernate Community:**](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=970014)

> I was able to set the
>   hibernate.use_reflection_optimizer
>   property in the web.config file as
>   follows. Note that the setting did not
>   work within the
>   hibernate-configuration section, so I
>   had to place it in a new nhibernate
>   section. The code now appears to be
>   working in a medium trust environment
>   ( godaddy )

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration"
             type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"
             requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="nhibernate"
             type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">blahblah</property>
      </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>

  <nhibernate>
    <add key="hibernate.use_reflection_optimizer" value="false" />
  </nhibernate>
```

Comment: Yes I did, but with no luck. NH seems to ignore <hibernate> section in App.config, it just looks for <hibernate-configuration> where you can't define this setting...

Comment: @Sapphire: please take a loot at my edit and see if that forum answer helps you too.